# Sign PDF from usb Token Using MSCAPI & ITEXT

Tags: java, encryption, itext, digital-signature, mscapi

can anyone give me a simle example of pdf signing from usb token using MSCAPI and ITEXT. I do not want to use a fixed ocsp string.

I tried to follow this
 [Digital Signature book](http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures)  but it did not work. My code was:

```
        LoggerFactory.getInstance().setLogger(new SysoLogger());
        BouncyCastleProvider providerBC = new BouncyCastleProvider();
        Security.addProvider(providerBC);
        SunMSCAPI provdierMSCAP = new SunMSCAPI();
        Security.addProvider(provdierMSCAP);
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
        ks.load(null, null);

        String alias = (String)ks.aliases().nextElement();
        PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey)ks.getKey(alias, null);
        Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);


        PdfReader pdfreader = new PdfReader("HelloWorld.pdf");
        FileOutputStream outputFile = new FileOutputStream("Signed.pdf");
        PdfStamper pdfstamper;

        pdfstamper =  PdfStamper.createSignature(pdfreader, outputFile, '\0', null, true);

        PdfSignatureAppearance sap = pdfstamper.getSignatureAppearance();
        sap.setCrypto(pk, chain, null, PdfSignatureAppearance.SELF_SIGNED);
        sap.setReason("Test");
        sap.setLocation("Dhaka");

        sap.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(10, 10, 50, 30), 1, "Test");
        pdfstamper.close();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully Signed");
```

And it is giving me following error:

```
        java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I tried use itext 5.2.1/itextpdf-5.3.5 and bcmail-jdk16-1.46, bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar, bctsp-jdk16-1.46.jar.

Can anyone help ? please ................

Comment: where do u put your certificate path?

Comment: Its not certificate (p12) file I want to use. i want to load the usb driver (from MSCAPI - Microsoft Cryptographic API)......

Comment: There's a contradiction in your question. You say you've read my book, but you're still using the setCrypto() method. If you've read my book, you'd know that this method shouldn't be used anymore.

Comment: Oh my God !!! are you the writer 'Bruno' ? At first, Thanks for writing such an awesome book. Its a treasure for newbie like me. I tried many codes but none of them actually worked. I tried your code too. The above code is only one the many code I tried with. Also, as a totally newbie, I should not say but I think the main problem is that, where the prompt of password of the usb token should come, it not coming in there. Can you give me a sample where my USB token (epass token 1000) will ask for giving password? Thanks a lot Bruno. You are a legend.........

Answer (score 0):

you are passing null values to load(),try this

```
ks.load(new FileInputStream("certificate_path"), keystore_password.toCharArray());
```

Comment: Yes, thats right. But, the book and other links said to pass null value so it will prompt to give password for providers (ikey/aladin/epass, I am using epass). Also I already used this method and got success in using p12 (certificate_path). But it is not applicable to USB Token. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Yea, I am trying. Thanks NK123 :)

Answer (score 0):

remove sap.setCrypto line. you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version, the setCrypo is replaced by the following lines:

```
ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
BouncyCastleProvider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
ExternalSignature signature = new PrivateKeySignature(key, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, provider.getName());
MakeSignature.signDetached(sap, digest, signature, chain,   null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);
```

You have to put *bcprov-jdk15on-1.60.jar* and *bcpkix-jdk15on-1.60.jar* in your classpath.